# visual studio pointing to my sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

in visual studio i have my code point to a sql server mdf file (in the APP_DATA folder).  and i keep having to syncronize this local data to my server.

is there anyway in visual studio i can just give it the connection string to my real server so i can debug directly against my server.

i know this may be a bit slower but it also might be easier as it eliminates going back and forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just change the connection string to point to your server